# golang indirect require causes issues in Cloud function build for package golang.org/x/sys/unix

Tags: go, google-cloud-functions

I am having a problem with deploying cloud function since one of my packages uses indirectly `golang.org/x/sys`

when using this version CF builds are passing any above seems to be failing

```
# golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20210119212857-b64e53b001e4
```

but after each run of `go get -u ./...` we are getting newer version and the CF build is failing with error

```
2022-10-02 09:03:07.208 CESTStep #1 - "build": # cloudfunctionissue/vendor/golang.org/x/sys/unix
2022-10-02 09:03:07.208 CESTStep #1 - "build": src/cloudfunctionissue/vendor/golang.org/x/sys/unix/syscall.go:83:16: undefined: unsafe.Slice
2022-10-02 09:03:07.208 CESTStep #1 - "build": src/cloudfunctionissue/vendor/golang.org/x/sys/unix/syscall_linux.go:2255:9: undefined: unsafe.Slice
2022-10-02 09:03:07.208 CESTStep #1 - "build": src/cloudfunctionissue/vendor/golang.org/x/sys/unix/syscall_unix.go:118:7: undefined: unsafe.Slice
2022-10-02 09:03:07.208 CESTStep #1 - "build": src/cloudfunctionissue/vendor/golang.org/x/sys/unix/sysvshm_unix.go:33:7: undefined: unsafe.Slice
```

seems this doc does not explain the problem enough for me https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-go#using_a_vendor_directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your answer, and yes I agree with you that my issue come with newer version of go. However we found the work around to this problem by updating only packages which are imported directly, and skip the indirect updates.

```bash
#!/bin/sh  
module=$(go list -f '{{.Module.Path}}' .)

go mod tidy
go get -d -t $(go mod graph | grep "^$module" | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | sed 's/@.*/@upgrade/g')
go mod tidy
go mod download
```

after applying this script to dockerfile we are building our CF without of issues.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because of runtime. [unsafe.Slice](https://pkg.go.dev/unsafe@go1.17#Slice) was introduced in `go v1.17` but currently [cloud functions support `v1.16`](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/go-runtime).  Somehow your code invoked [syscall.go:83.16](https://cs.opensource.google/go/x/sys/+/master:unix/syscall.go;l=83) and other packages. Hence you are getting above error. Either try to revert back or determine what is invoking these packages.